Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit in react project
i have created smart contract in remix and everything work currect :
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity ^0.6.12;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import "./ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";
import "./IERC20.sol";

contract MultiSend is Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    event TokensSent(address token, address sender, uint256 total);
    event TokenReceived(address token, address receiver, uint256 amount);
    event ETHSent(address sender, uint256 total);
    event ETHReceived(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event TokenAddressChanged(address newAddress);

    address public tokenAddress;

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) public {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
    }

    fallback() external {
        revert();
    }

    function sendToken(
        address _aa,
        address _ba,
        uint256 _av,
        uint256 _bv
    ) public nonReentrant returns (bool) {
        require(_aa != address(0), "please check address");
        require(_ba != address(0), "please check address");
        require(_av > 0, "please check amount");
        require(_bv > 0, "please check amount");
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        require(
            token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= _av + _bv,
            "please check approve"
        );
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _aa, _av);
        emit TokenReceived(tokenAddress, _aa, _av);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _ba, _bv);
        emit TokenReceived(tokenAddress, _ba, _bv);
        emit TokensSent(tokenAddress, msg.sender, _av + _bv);
        return true;
    }

    function sendERC20(address[] memory _receiver, uint256[] memory _amount)
        public
        nonReentrant
        returns (bool)
    {
        uint256 totalSend = 0;
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        require(_receiver.length <= 100, "receiver list is overload!");
        require(
            _receiver.length == _amount.length,
            "lacking of amount infomation, please check again!"
        );
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < _receiver.length; j++) {
            token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _receiver[j], _amount[j]);
            emit TokenReceived(tokenAddress, _receiver[j], _amount[j]);
            totalSend += _amount[j];
        }
        emit TokensSent(tokenAddress, msg.sender, totalSend);
        return true;
    }

    function sendCoin(address[] memory _receiver, uint256[] memory _amount)
        public
        payable
        nonReentrant
        returns (bool)
    {
        require(_receiver.length <= 100, "receiver list is overload!");
        require(
            _receiver.length == _amount.length,
            "lacking of amount infomation, please check again!"
        );

        uint256 total = msg.value;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _receiver.length; i++) {
            require(total >= _amount[i]);
            (bool success, ) = payable(_receiver[i]).call{value: _amount[i]}(
                ""
            );
            require(success, "Transfer failed.");
            emit ETHReceived(_receiver[i], _amount[i]);
            total = total.sub(_amount[i]);
        }
        emit ETHSent(msg.sender, msg.value);
        return true;
    }

    function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress)
        external
        onlyOwner
        returns (bool)
    {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
        emit TokenAddressChanged(_tokenAddress);
        return true;
    }
}

in remix at the begning i approve contract address for pay x amount of token , and after that i call sendERC20 Function for send multi payment and every thing i currect .
but when i want to use it in react , it show me this error in metamask and transaction getting faild , i want want to know whats the problem ?
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

function MultiSendToken() {
  const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(null);
  const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
  const [multiSendContractAddress, setMultiSendContractAddress] = useState('0xf5ba214d32Ac6f9F27e970207da342D299f325d7');
  const [tokenAddress, setTokenAddress] = useState('0x3b7513042790a6e07729b40138cCB46547FB4e3A'); // Token contract address
  const [addressA, setAddressA] = useState('0x8EC1E147971A9f4dA725CCc031E8F1c85c4E8F6a');
  const [addressB, setAddressB] = useState('0x8EC1E147971A9f4dA725CCc031E8F1c85c4E8F6a');
  const [amountA, setAmountA] = useState('1');
  const [amountB, setAmountB] = useState('1');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const web3Instance = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      setWeb3(web3Instance);
      window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
        .then(accounts => {
          setAccount(accounts[0]);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error('User denied account access or error occurred:', err);
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please install MetaMask!');
    }
  }, []);

  const approveTokens = async () => {
    const totalAmount = (parseFloat(amountA) + parseFloat(amountB)).toString();
    const tokenABI = [{
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [{ "name": "_spender", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" }],
      "name": "approve",
      "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }],
      "type": "function"
    }];
    const tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenABI, tokenAddress);
    const totalAmountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(totalAmount, 'mwei'); // Convert total amount to wei with 6 decimals

    try {
      await tokenContract.methods.approve(multiSendContractAddress, totalAmountInWei).call({ from: account });
      console.log('Approval successful for total amount:', totalAmountInWei);
      sendToken(); // Proceed to send tokens after approval
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Approval failed:', error);
      alert('Approval failed. Check console for more details.');
    }
  };

  const sendToken = async () => {
    const multiSendABI = [
      {
        "inputs": [
          { "name": "_aa", "type": "address" },
          { "name": "_ba", "type": "address" },
          { "name": "_av", "type": "uint256" },
          { "name": "_bv", "type": "uint256" }
        ],
        "name": "sendToken",
        "outputs": [{ "name": "", "type": "bool" }],
        "type": "function",
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable"
      }
    ];
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(multiSendABI, multiSendContractAddress);
    const avInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountA, 'mwei'); // Converting to smallest unit based on 6 decimals
    const bvInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountB, 'mwei');

    try {
      const response = await contract.methods.sendToken(addressA, addressB, avInWei, bvInWei).send({ from: account });
      console.log('Transaction Successful:', response);
      alert('Tokens sent successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to send tokens:', error);
      alert('Transaction failed! See console for details.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>MultiSend Token Transfer</h2>
      <input type="text" value={tokenAddress} onChange={e => setTokenAddress(e.target.value)} placeholder="Token Contract Address" />
      <input type="text" value={multiSendContractAddress} onChange={e => setMultiSendContractAddress(e.target.value)} placeholder="MultiSend Contract Address" />
      <input type="text" value={addressA} onChange={e => setAddressA(e.target.value)} placeholder="Address A" />
      <input type="text" value={addressB} onChange={e => setAddressB(e.target.value)} placeholder="Address B" />
      <input type="text" value={amountA} onChange={e => setAmountA(e.target.value)} placeholder="Amount for Address A" />
      <input type="text" value={amountB} onChange={e => setAmountB(e.target.value)} placeholder="Amount for Address B" />
      <button onClick={approveTokens}>Approve and Send Tokens</button>
    </div>
  );
}

Error Message :
export default MultiSendToken;
Failed to send tokens: TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
 {"blockHash":"0xa4fccf0ecacf834f634b090ce0c6dbb1d6e14f18f3a61d3d7057984bdb185913","blockNumber":"6238953","cumulativeGasUsed":"219787","effectiveGasPrice":"2500000015","from":"0x53a1d6bab5d93e93b7be978f109967c581e4b683","gasUsed":"37505","logs":[{"address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010","topics":["0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010","0x00000000000000000000000053a1d6bab5d93e93b7be978f109967c581e4b683","0x00000000000000000000000009207a6efee346cb3e4a54ac18523e3715d38b3f"],"data":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005546c881790000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006e84ce7162498310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c66c71f3e72ecad40900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006e7f7a04da31f310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c66c72492df74c4d09","blockNumber":"6238953","transactionHash":"0xe3fcda0fb3706298a2f5c43356f9076887b2f368a34d938ebdeaf2dca9a9abd9","transactionIndex":"2","blockHash":"0xa4fccf0ecacf834f634b090ce0c6dbb1d6e14f18f3a61d3d7057984bdb185913","logIndex":"6","removed":false}],"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000004000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000001000000400000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000100000","status":"0","to":"0xf5ba214d32ac6f9f27e970207da342d299f325d7","transactionHash":"0xe3fcda0fb3706298a2f5c43356f9076887b2f368a34d938ebdeaf2dca9a9abd9","transactionIndex":"2","type":"2","events":{}}



I had the same error before and asked on ethereum. from the answer:

What probably happens is that Metamask runs a static call to the
contract with the same parameters, to simulate what would happen if
the transaction took place. If it notices that the static call
reverts, it gives you this error - because most likely the real
transaction would revert as well.

one of the arguments of sendToken function has wrong type. log all of the arguments to see their value.
